# Upgrading CENTOS 6 to PHP 5.5 Errors

Tags: centos6

I want to upgrade my PHP version. When updating to PHP 5.5

```
yum -y install php55w php55w-opcache
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Package: php55w-opcache-5.5.30-2.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: php55w-common(x86-64) = 5.5.30-2.w6
           Available: php55w-common-5.5.30-2.w6.x86_64 (webtatic)
               php55w-common(x86-64) = 5.5.30-2.w6
```

How can i fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error indicates, this should do the trick:

```
yum install php55w-common
```

Then your initial command should work:

```
yum install php55w php55w-opcache
```

Or combine into one:

```
yum install php55w-common php55w php55w-opcache
```

In case of repo related problems like obsolete packages, force use of a specific repo like so, in this case using remi which contains newer versions of php than most stock OS repo's include:

```
yum --disablerepo="*" --enablerepo="remi" install php55w-common php55w php55w-opcache
```

Do note though that PHP 5.5 is already outdated too:

http://php.net/supported-versions.php

5.6 would be a much better choice for long term support, security and speed.

Comment: when i use the first command i get this: Package php55w-common-5.5.30-2.w6.x86_64 is obsoleted by php-common-5.5.30-1.el6.remi.x86_64 which is already installed
Nothing to do

Comment: See edits, in that case it would be better to force php installation through the remi repo you have enabled. Then again, 5.6 would be a better choice of your application code supports it.

Comment: this worked did the trick without any errors, thanks! Now i can't restart httpd, please see my topic: http://serverfault.com/questions/734820/cant-start-httpd-centos-6-apache-2-2