# Can't start httpd centos 6 apache 2.2

Tags: apache-2.2, centos6

I try to start httpd on centos 6 / apache 2.2 but get the following error:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd start
Starting httpd: [Sun Nov 08 20:47:36 2015] [warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
Syntax error on line 5 of /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-directories.conf:
Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
                                                           [FAILED]
```

After searching i found some solutions like changing

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

to

```
Require all denied
```

But this is for apache 2.4 and i'm running 2.2

Kinda stuck here and all the websites are down. Can anybody help me out?

EDIT:

This is my httpd-directories.conf file:

```
<Directory />
    Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride None

        Order Deny,Allow
        Deny from All
</Directory>

<Directory /home>
        AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit Options=Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,ExecCGI,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch,None
        Options IncludesNoExec Includes SymLinksIfOwnerMatch ExecCGI

        <Limit GET POST OPTIONS PROPFIND>
                Order allow,deny
                Allow from all
        </Limit>
        <LimitExcept GET POST OPTIONS PROPFIND>
                Order deny,allow
                Deny from all
        </LimitExcept>
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/html>
        Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo Indexes Limit Options=Includes,IncludesNOEXEC,Indexes,ExecCGI,MultiViews,SymLinksIfOwnerMatch,None

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        <IfModule mod_suphp.c>
                suPHP_Engine On
                suPHP_UserGroup webapps webapps
                SetEnv PHP_INI_SCAN_DIR
        </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/cgi-bin>
        AllowOverride None
        Options None

        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
</Directory>
```

Comment: Does that httpd-directories.conf file look exactly like this? https://github.com/dmikusa-pivotal/cf-php-apache-buildpack/blob/master/default/httpd/2.2/extra/httpd-directories.conf Please post the full contents. Also please verify your Apache version: httpd -v

Comment: @JayMcTee Edited my original question with the content of my httpd-directories.conf file

Comment: Did you explicitly verify the httpd version with httpd -v? And do check this module is there too: httpd -M | grep authz_host

Comment: Why did you restart it? Did you make any changes ?

Comment: @Iain i needed it to restart after upgrading php

Comment: @JayMcTee Apache/2.2.15 (Unix) httpd -M | grep authz_host
[Sun Nov 08 21:51:58 2015] [warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
Syntax error on line 5 of /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-directories.conf:
Invalid command 'Order', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration

Answer (score 3):

It looks like you're missing the authz_host module, ensure that your `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf` file has a line like

```
LoadModule authz_host_module modules/mod_authz_host.so
```

in it. If I comment that line out of my httpd.conf, I get the same error as you see.

Comment: Where should i add that line? because i don't see any other *.so modules getting loaded in that file

Comment: If this is a standard C6 system then the file I mention is where it should go. If it's a non standard system who knows.

Comment: I don't really know if this is a standard or none standard system, i'm not the most experienced system admin. When i edit the file like you said i get the error /etc/init.d/httpd start
Starting httpd: [Sun Nov 08 22:11:24 2015] [warn] module php5_module is already loaded, skipping
Syntax error on line 2 of /etc/httpd/conf/extra/httpd-php-handlers.conf:
Invalid command 'AddHandler', perhaps misspelled or defined by a module not included in the server configuration
                                                           [FAILED]

Comment: Your config is seriously boned.  It's probably time to take off and nuke it from orbit.

Comment: This is a cpanel sysetm ?

Answer (score -1):

Some untested thoughts:

Should the / in the opening  tag be quoted?

```
<Directory "/">
```

Also, the documentation shows lowercase for Deny and Allow directives.

```
Order deny,allow
```

Example:

```
<Directory "/">
    Options SymLinksIfOwnerMatch
        AllowOverride None
        Order deny,allow
        Deny from All
</Directory>
```

Comment: I have working systems where the directory paths are not quoted. The same systems have Allow and Deny.